# Periodic HTML Text Centering

Tags: javascript, html

Im building a stopwatch with javascript and the issue is that although centering does work, the dynamic nature of the stopwatch means a very jittery effect when it constantly tries to recenter on every new number. As some  numbers are wider or thinner, it means it keeps on "jittering". This is very distracting.

However, I still do wish for the time to centered on screen. I had success with keeping the time on just one side of the screen however it was not aesthetically pleasing. I was wondering if there was a way to only center the text once in say 1 min? (I was thinking of centering and then using padding to pad up to where it was centered, thus meaning it would be aligned against the padding and maybe redoing this proccess every 30secs or something)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To stop the jittering effect, you could place the text inside a div and center the div.

```
stopwatch_container{
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto; /*This will center the div*/ 
}

stopwatch_text {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm i tried this. the idea is fantastic! however, when i try this the width is ok for a while but then it overflows and goes onto the next line. I think it needs to be able to dynamically increase but i dont know how

Comment: delete width: 100px and add white-space: nowrap. That should work.

Comment: no, unfortunately now it just pushes the whole thing to the left side margin. I thought that margin:auto needed a declared width?